# Arraylist Inserting a value before the last

Tags: java, arraylist, nodes

I'm trying to insert a value before the last value in an arraylist. This is written generically.

```
public class ArrayList
{
private Object[] array;
private int capacity;
private int size;
private final int InitialCap = 10;

//constructor of list
public ArrayList()
{
array = new Object[InitialCap];
capacity - InitialCap;
size = 0;
}
}


public static void main(String[] args)
{
int value = 5;
array.add(array.size()-2, value);
}
```

Comment: Why aren't you sure?

Comment: I see an array, where is your `ArrayList`?

Comment: I think the OP is writing his/her own ArrayList class

Comment: `ArrayList` (which you are not using) has [`add(int index, E element)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#add(int,%20E)) method that can do just that

Comment: your method signature indicates that the method returns an Object type, but your method body doesn't have a return statement. What's up with that?

Comment: This is if the Arraylist is already created and I want to add a value at the second to last value.

Comment: Are you trying to create your own ArrayList? Why not just use java.util.ArrayList?

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of problems with this code. first you never defined capacity but are trying to use it in your constructor. Which is impossible. if you mean another class should do that, you need another constructor to do that or at least setter method and a constructor that does not need capacity set in initialization. You are also calling array from a static method without it being static. If you fix these you get something like this:

public class ArrayList {

```
private static final int InitialCap = 10;
private static Object[] array = new Object[InitialCap];

public static void main(String[] args)
{
    int value = 5;
    array[InitialCap-2] = value;
    System.out.println(array);
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You aren't using an ArrayList in this code. You are using a simple array and they're different things. If you were using an ArrayList however, you could do it like this:

```
list.add(list.size()-2, objectName);
```

Plus, your for-loop only runs once. i starts at 5, the loop runs, i lowers to 4, the loop realizes i is too low and stops looping.

Comment: I understand what you're saying there, but I'm not sure what parameters I would pass for the method.Unless what you put would be the parameters?

`public void add(list.size()-2, whatgoeshere?)
{
if(index <0 || index > size)
throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException("Invalid index " +index);

}`

Comment: This is assuming you have an ArrayList named 'list'. Then the first argument is correct but you'd have to swap 'objectName' for the name of the object you want to insert. Remember that if you want to add an integer you'll have to first wrap it in the Integer wrapper class http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html

Comment: Sorry I don't know why the comments didnt save the spaces

Comment: So I could have public void add(list.size()-2, Int value) if I was trying to insert an int value before the last value in the arraylist?

Comment: I am using the method built into ArrayLists. You are creating a new method.

Comment: Sorry I'm very confused. So, what you're saying is that I can just call this list.add(list.size()-2, value) right from the main method?

Comment: Yes, but only if 'list' is an ArrayList (which your array in your post isn't).

Comment: I edited the original code, is that what you were looking for? Would something like that work? How would I add a generic value instead of harcoding 5? Just leave it Object name?